# SQL Server investigating time out error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlperformance, query-tuning

I've been tasked with investigating timeout error for an existing ETL. I would like to access logs of previous ETL run to identify where the timeout occurs.
The ETL sits on Azure and one task keeps failing.

The task that keeps failing, effectively kicks off a stored procedure on SQL Server. I was wondering whether it is possible for me to use some logs and statistics to do my investigation. I know the tables used in the stored procedure, so this would hopefully give me a starting point. But essentially I am after the following information.

1. What table the time out occurs
2. What causes the time out i.e. is it a deadlock
3. What other processes i.e. stored procedures use the affected table.

What functionalities can I use in SQL Server to do some digging. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> The task that keeps failing, effectively kicks off a stored procedure on SQL Server

I recommend fine tuning this procedure and try updating statistics for the tables involved in this procedure.This should take care of most of the time outs..

> What table the time out occurs

There should be error logged in azure log analytics

> What causes the time out i.e. is it a deadlock

Time out is not a deadlock

Most of the causes of Timeouts are related to poorly performing procedure/query..In our case, we are able to get past this time outs by tuning the query involved and also changing the time out settings

Answer (score 0):

Sharingan,

Steps within the stored procedure are not causing the timeout. The client calling the SP has a timeout value, and if the SP takes longer than that, it "thinks" something is wrong. This does not mean your SP is architected wrong, or that it actually failed.

One approach would be to create a logging table, and in your stored procedure, at the beginning, delete all rows from this table (it is a TEMP table that is cleared each time the SP runs). Then before each step in the procedure, insert a row into your logging table with something like 'Starting employee ETL...', and after the step 'Completed Employee ETL...'.

You can also check to see if an error has occurred after each step, and write the error message to this table. This effectively becomes your own log.

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
   -- Add Error_Message to your table
END
```

If the calling process does not have the timeout value properly set, you may see that the SP actually finishes (by examining your log), but the client mistakenly thinks something is wrong because the timeout value has been exceeded. A timeout error at the client won't stop SQL Server from marching on with the work.

Can you try to run the Stored Procedure by itself, from SSMS, for example? If this works you're on your way to tracking down the issue, but it's important to distinguish if it is SQL, or your client, like an Azure Logic App, or whatever is launching the ETL process. You may need to fabricate/simulate any parameters passed into the SP, but that should be easy in SSMS.

You can also break a big SP into a bunch of smaller ones, and add more steps to your ETL client, instead of one huge SP call. This may force you to implement transient error handling, but that might be manageable in your situation.

Good luck!